# Why is list() necessary in aggregate()

Tags: r, list, aggregate

When using `aggregate()` by columns you specify which columns you want to e.g summarise over in a list.

For instance:

```
aggregate(mtcars$qsec, by = list(as.factor(mtcars$cyl),
                                      as.factor(mtcars$carb)), FUN = sum)

 Group.1 Group.2      x
1       4       1  96.89
2       6       1  39.66
3       4       2 113.62
4       8       2  68.24
5       8       3  53.00
6       6       4  70.68
7       8       4  98.97
8       6       6  15.50
9       8       8  14.60
```

Why is a `list()` necessary here, why not a vector?

Comment: In your example you have two vectors in `by=`. BTW: I prefer the formula interface of `aggregate()`, e.g.: `aggregate(qsec ~ cyl, data=mtcars, FUN = sum)`

Comment: @jogo that is because I want to summarise over two vectors.

Comment: `aggregate(qsec ~ cyl + carb, data=mtcars, FUN = sum)`

Comment: Thanks, that is a better syntax but I'm still interested in an answer of my question :)

Comment: But it is clear that it can not be a single vector if you are using two grouping variables, isn't it? The function `aggregate()` wants a list for that parameter. compare with `library("fortunes"); fortune(85)`

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's obvious, however it seems logical. It's just that I think most people expect the syntax to be `by = c("column1", "column2")` rather than a list.

Comment: In that case you don't give `aggregate` the data but the column names. How is `aggregate` supposed to know, that it should look in `mtcars` for these names and not somewhere else? `aggregate` wants data, not names of data. That's what `fortune(85)` says. If you want something different, you can go ahead and write yourself a wrapper function.

Comment: @Bernhard my initial thought was `c(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$carb)` would be enough?

Comment: But this is concatenating the vectors and leads to a single vector twice the length. You want two different vectors of the same length, not a single longer one.

Comment: Thanks alot @Bernhard, that makes sense.